# why it says access denied for roles="Admin"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to set Authorize tag in my controller and when I do so, it says that your access to that controller is denied.
but in the database, everything looks good.
then what is the problem?
*I should mention that I use individual accounts authentication type

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

[image: pic3]

[image: pic4]

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public IActionResult ContactUs()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Hello Guys I found my answer in program.cs file

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

Answer (score 0):

Try to log out from your application and log in again.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing role services

```cs
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(...)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
...
```